# Firefox addon panel font

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-sdk

I am experiencing a little trouble to add a font into a panel for my firefox extension.
Here is a simplified code :

> main.js

```
var panel = panels.Panel({
  contentURL: self.data.url("panel.html"),
});
```

> panel.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="font.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    lorem ...
    <button>Deactivate</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

> font.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyFont';
  src: url('MyFont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

> style.css

```
.wrapper {
  font-family: 'MyFont', sans-serif;
}
```

Here is the result :

[image: firefox]

For a comparison, here is the result for chrome :

[image: chrome]

The font files used are the same.

Do you have any idea what can cause this and how to fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: Where do you store the `MyFont.woff` file?

Comment: At the same level as `font.css`... But with another font, like a Web safe font, the result seems to be the same...

Comment: Is there any warning or error in the Browser Console?

Comment: no, I believe that the font is correctly loaded but the result is really not good...